# Extract substring with a specific pattern in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I have a column with this sample data. I need to extract all substring that starts with "M6". Is there a way to do it with regexp_extract?

| Data Column |
| --- |
| HEY01230328_M6K21SG_UNO_NYC_241 |
| M6EW2BJ_UNO_NYC_251 |
| M6HW2WL_UNO_NYC_251 |
| HEY08460329_NA_M6LAB3D_UNO_NYC_241 |

| Desired Output |
| --- |
| M6K21SG |
| M6EW2BJ |
| M6HW2WL |
| M6LAB3D |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
SELECT colname FROM tableName WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(colname, ".*(M6[^_]*).*",1)
```

Regex used:

```
.*(M6[^_]*).*
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/OkRHnF/1)

**Explanation:**

- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a newline character
- `(M6[^_]*)` - matches `M6` followed by 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `_`. So, after M6, it keeps on matching everything until it finds the next `_`. The parenthesis is used to store this sub-match in Group 1
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a newline character